# glDrawArrays segfault after creating IBO

Tags: opengl

I have a bunch of elements currently rendering from a VBO using `glDrawArrays` without issues.

When I added an IBO though, even without any rendering code that uses it, I got crashes on `glDrawArrays`.

I checked all glBindBuffer calls 10 times over, the issue is not there. But it is related to the size of the IBO. Here's the additional code that triggers crashes on glDrawArrays:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

If `size` is above around 5kb, I start getting crashes. The crashes are consistent, but depend on which elements I'm rendering. For example, at 6kb I don't immediately crash, but if I pull down another UI element that is initially hidden, it crashes while rendering that. If I set it above around 8kb, I will always immediately crash on the first element using `glDrawArrays`.

My hunch is that the `glBufferData` call is somehow corrupting memory somewhere, given the correlation of `size` to the likelihood of crashing, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am running on x64 Linux using official nVidia drivers.

Edit: Here's the glDrawArrays code:

```
cgGLBindProgram(program);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
cgGLEnableClientState(verts);
cgGLSetParameterPointer(verts, vertSize, GL_FLOAT, stride, reinterpret_cast<void*>(vertoffset);
gGLEnableClientState(texcoords);
cgGLSetParameterPointer(texcoords, tcSize, GL_FLOAT, tcstride, reinterpret_cast<void*>(tcoffset);
cgSetMatrixParameterfc(matrix, (*m)[0]);   // ortho matrix
cgGLSetParameter4f(color, f1, f2, f3, f4);
cgGLBindProgram(fragmentProgram);
cgGLSetTextureParameter(texture, tex->getID());
cgGLEnableTextureParameter(texture);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, first, vertCount);
```

Shaders used:

```
output ortho(float2 position : POSITION, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0, uniform float4 color : COLOR, uniform float4x4 ortho_proj) {
    output OUT;

    OUT.position = mul(float4(position, 0, 1), ortho_proj);
    OUT.color = color;
    OUT.texCoord = texCoord;

    return OUT;
}

void textured(float4 color : COLOR, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0, out float4 outColor, uniform sampler2D texture) {
    outColor = tex2D(texture, texCoord) * color;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code, like glDrawArrays and everything leading to it.

Comment: Question updated with more code.